# Display open checklist items on face of card

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-lists

Is it possible to show open checklist items on the face of the card without having to drill into the card itself?

Answer (score 1):

Switched to [springpad](http://www.springpad.com) since this doesn't appear to be a Trello feature.

Comment: Ok, that was quick, just learned springpad is shutting down on 6/25/14, shame, it's a great app